# How to pass background image url from database to view in mvc?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

i have a table named "Post" and each post has post image,the image saved in table as a string , when i am viewing the post i need to put the image as a css background image ,the code i wrote is:

```
<div style = "background-image : url('~/Uploads/@Model.postimage')"></div
```

and it isn't get the image !!

Comment: <div style= "background-image : url ('~/Uploads/@Model.postimage')">

Comment: show us what is the exact data in the @Model.postImage

Comment: @Model.PostImage = image name that stored in the table and the full url to represent is ~/Uploads/"image name that stored in @model.postimage"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your ~ is the root cause of this issue.

Use

```
<div style = "background-image : url('../Uploads/@Model.postimage')"></div>
```

or

```
<div style = "background-image : url('@Model.postimage')"></div>
```

The second option is better. Add the absolute URL through `@Model.postimage`

**UPDATE**

you can also use the helper Url.Content(), if you want to stick with ~

```
<div style="background-image : url('@Url.Content("~/Uploads/" + Model.postimage)')"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the helper `Url.Content()`, with the "~"-path inside the method call:

```
<div style="background-image : url('@Url.Content("~/Uploads/" + Model.postimage)')"></div>
```

Comment: If my answer worked then maybe the other answer that copied my solution shouldn't be the one that you accept.

Answer (score 0):

background image url from database to view in mvc

**Use:**

```
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
     style="background-image : url('@Url.Content("~/assets/images/"+myWorks.ImageName)')">
    </dv>
```